# convert an xmi file to xml file using python

Tags: python, xml, xmi

I need to convert an activity diagram in xmi format to xml format.Is this conversion possible using python?Are there any tools to convert xmi files to xml?

Comment: XMI files are already XML.

Answer (score 1):

Converting XML to XML is usually called [XML transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT). For Python you can use [libxsltmod](http://www.rexx.com/~dkuhlman/#libxsltmod) to perform XML transformations by using XSLT 'stylesheets'.

Answer (score 1):

As Ignacio says, the problem may not be that the target tool expects XML but that probably expects a diffent XMI format.

Unfortunately, each tool follows its own interpretation of the XMI standard so two modeling tools will most likely generate two incompatible XMI files for the same model. See an example in this "[model once open anywhere not true](http://modeling-languages.com/blog/content/model-once-open-anywhere-definitely-not-true-example)" post

Answer (score 1):

you can get the information that you need (classes and attribute ...) from any `file.xmi` this [doc](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/xml.dom.minidom.html) maybe help

```
from xml.dom import minidom
xmldoc = minidom.parse('file.xmi')
        for element in xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("UML:Class"):
                print(" -> UML:Class ",element.getAttribute('name'))
                for a in element.getElementsByTagName("UML:Attribute"):
                        print("   -> UML:Attr : ",a.getAttribute('name'))
```