# convert an activity diagram in xmi to xml format

Tags: python, xml, xmi, activity-diagram

I have created an activity diagram in xmi format using a tool called Umbrello.I also use a tool called Uml2owfn that converts activity diagram in xml format to petri net.It will not accept xmi input.So I need to transform xmi to xml.Is this possible using python?Is there any tool that performs this conversion?

Comment: possible duplicate of [convert an xmi file to xml file using python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6199504/convert-an-xmi-file-to-xml-file-using-python)